# GooglePlus userProfile API returns error when trying to access using access-token retrieved using Google Service Account

Tags: google-plus, service-accounts

I was able to retrieve access-token using Google Service account but when I tried to use the same access-token to retrieve GooglePlus User Profile API I'm getting the error mentioned below:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

I used scope value as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` while retrieving access-token using Google service account and I was able to fetch access-token, but then if I try to use the same access-token to request User profile API- I.e
`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?prettyprint=true` I get the error above.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the account that has done the authentication does not have a Google+ account/profile. For testing, you may wish to replace the "me" with the profile ID in question to verify this. In production, of course, you should catch this error and indicate that they don't have a Google+ profile.

If you need to check for a Google login, even if they don't have a Google+ profile, you can use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` scope. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login for more details.